How to modify terminal in ubuntu
Okay so I tried searching around but couldn't find the answer, probably because I might be dumb. I'm trying to use this terminal theme with vim: https://github.com/sonph/onehalf
To install the vim colors I just placed the colors file in
.vim/colors

How do I make my ubuntu terminal also look like that? I want it to look like this (the light version):
https://vimcolorschemes.com/sonph/onehalf
I don't know what to do with the .terminal file. Where do I place this file:
https://github.com/sonph/onehalf/blob/master/terminal/OneHalfLight.terminal
? Or am I supposed to use this .sh file?
https://github.com/sonph/onehalf/blob/master/gnome-terminal/onehalflight.sh
Please help. Thank you. :)
Edit: Forgot to mention
So I cloned the repo into my ~ directory. Then did
source ./onehalf/gnome-terminal/onehalflight.sh

But my terminal tab is not blue, like in this photo:
https://vimcolorschemes.com/sonph/onehalf
It is gray. :( I am using Ubuntu, the photo looks like it is MacOS? Is that why?

Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1514992/how-to-change-terminal-color-scheme-with-terminal-file

If you navigate to that repo and enter a specific console type, there is a readme in the folder. For instance if you wget the files for the gome-terminal you then have to source them and apply them in preferences provided by your console. In short it depends on your desktop environment or console in use, and there are readme.md files for each supported type in their respective folders within the repo.

Hi thank you. Sorry forgot to mention
So I cloned the repo into my ~ directory. Then did
source ./onehalf/gnome-terminal/onehalflight.sh
But my terminal tab is not blue, like in this photo:
https://vimcolorschemes.com/sonph/onehalf
It is gray. :( I am using Ubuntu, the photo looks like it is MacOS? Is that why?

I'm not sure of the caveats on why certain settings wouldn't apply themselves. I would look in preferences for the terminal and see that there is no overriding setting. Also it could be that it is MacOS. But I don't think MacOS uses gnome. I do know my tabs also did not change when I sourced, only the general colors and syntax highlighting.
